# What is Vandermonde's formula with multisets?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, multisets

I need Vandermonde's formula in multi-set form. I modified the original formula but I get a mess with too many letters everywhere, is there a nice representation?

Here's the original:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k}{{m \choose j}{n \choose k-j}={m+n \choose k}} .$$

I get,
$$ \def\multiset#1#2{\left(\!\left({#1\atopwithdelims..#2}\right)\!\right)} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \multiset{m+k+1}{k}\multiset{n+k-j+1}{k-j}=\multiset{m+n+k+1}{k} .$$
Is there a less cumbersome way of writing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vandermonde's identity holds true with multisets as well.

A direct way to prove is by using convolution of generating functions.

In case of binomials, we need to get $[x^k]$ from $\left(1+x\right)^m\left(1+x\right)^n$.

For your question, the gf of $$a_k = \multiset{m}{k} = \binom{m+k-1}{k}$$ is 
\begin{align*}
  G(x) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} a_k x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^m}
\end{align*}
and the gf of $$b_k = \multiset{n}{k} = \binom{n+k-1}{k}$$ is 
\begin{align*}
  H(x) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} b_k x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^n}
\end{align*}
and we need to get $[x^k]$ from $G(x)\cdot H(x)$, hence,
\begin{align*}
  G(x)\cdot H(x) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} \left(\sum_{j=0}^k a_j b_{k-j} \right)x^k \\
  &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+n}} \\
  &= \sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{m+n+k-1}{k} x^k
\end{align*}
or in other words 
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{j=0}^k \multiset{m}{j}\multiset{n}{k-j} &= \multiset{m+n}{k}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. I found an easy way to see this is indeed the case some days ago.

Comment: You are welcome.